# How to get end date of month in Automation Anywhere?

Tags: rpa

How can we get Last day of the month, no matter what current date is but need to get the last date value of that particular month? Is there any other way except by giving the last day values and respected month in an array? Please need advice

Comment: How does the tag rpa have anything to do with this? How would an AI process build a date-time API based on on human interaction with.... something. [Edit] this question and make it clear what you want to do, show a [mcve], and tell us what result you get.

Comment: You can write a simple vbscript for this purpose and call it via the 'Run Script' command. Google "vbscript days in month" or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Save the below Python code and Open Program/File from AAE to Run it

import datetime

def last_day_of_month(any_day):
    next_month = any_day.replace(day=28) + datetime.timedelta(days=4) 
    return next_month - datetime.timedelta(days=next_month.day)

for month in range(1, 13):
    print(last_day_of_month(datetime.date(2018, month, 1)))